# Cursor vibrates

Tags: windows-7, mouse, itunes, touchpad

My cursor is vibrating. Does not vibrate under my admin login, only when I'm logged in under normal user account. I thought it may be a virus, so I did some troubleshooting, but couldn't find a virus. I had recently installed iTunes, and the icon looked different than it used to, so I thought maybe I had gotten duped somehow with that - uninstalled all iTunes/apple stuff, still vibrates. Tried removing wireless mouse & just using touchpad, but it still vibrates. Really don't get why it doesn't vibrate when I logged on to admin acct...any help out there?/ I'm on Windows 7 Home Premium, ToshibaSatellite P750 computer, Logitech mouse. Thanks!!

Comment: "vibrating"? You mean it moves when you don't touch the mouse?

Comment: Yes. Whenever the cursor is not in a spot where I'm typing, the "waiting" blue circle appears and the cursor & circle jiggle rapidly in the same spot - it doesn't jump from place to place

Comment: have you tried disabling the track pad? there are some instructions [here](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/11/disable-trackpad-windows-7-laptop/)

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems to me that under normal user account some part of a touchpad driver is misbehaving. Try disabling touchpad and see what happens. Also, lowering mouse sensitivity and updating driver either from Toshiba web site or from Windows Update may help.

Comment: Either the touch pad, or, more likely, the pointing stick. I had this problem and that was the answer.